# cakePHP router, route isn't working

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have this route:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/*',
    array('controller'=>'con3'),
    array('controller'=>'con1|con2')
            );
```

I am trying to direct every call to

```
/con1/x1/x2
```

to

```
/con3/x1/x2
```

and

```
/con2/y1/y2
```

to

```
/con3/y1/y2
```

it is not working, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require to route `/con3/` to `/con1/` and/or `/con2/` based on your own constraints what you require is a **Custom `Route class`**. For this there is no better place than [Mark Story's tutorial on custom `Route` classes](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp).

Otherwise, you could of course just extend your controllers (and leave the body empty) like this:

```
<?php
class Con3Controller extends Con1Controller{
    // maybe add model here if you don't have
    // var $uses in Con1Controller
    // otherwise, extend is just fine
}
?>
```

In this case you don't need to mess with connecting routes like you are right now. Object inheritance will take care of your "aliasing" for you.

Comment: Thanks @Oerd , but, how do i extend con3 from con1 AND from con2?

Comment: @yossi multiple inheritance is not something you can get out-of-the-box in PHP :) Now that I think I understand your requirements better, I have updated my answer.

Comment: that's probably the answer... shame on me expecting cake to offer a built-in solution :)  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like:

```
Router::connect( '/con1/:action/*', array( 'controller' => 'con3' ) );
Router::connect( '/con2/:action/*', array( 'controller' => 'con3' ) );
```

Comment: it's dirty.. i have 8 controllers with up to 10 aliases each.

Comment: @yossi having 10 aliases for each controller is not exactly "clean" :P Things can get out of hand in the future if you need to update your code

Comment: Indeed, but since it's based on keywords (as 'categories'), i have no other option. the only other way is using htaccess .. and it's the worst